# How to access variables from the ModelAndView in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a controller which returns a ModelAndView object

```
return new ModelAndView("operatorDetail", model);
```

I can then access the elements in the model object from my JSP page like this

```
<c:if test="${not empty operator and operator.regionId eq item.regionId}"
```

my question is, is there a way I can access those elements in my javascript code ?.
I thought about putting those values in an input element in HTML and make it hidden and access their values, but is there a more practical way?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can have something like this. Declare `var in jsp`

`<c:set var="yourJspVar" scope="session" value=" your object"/>`

and in `java-script`   set variable like

```
<script>
  var jsVar = '${yourJspVar}';
  alert(jsVar);
</script>
```